MSSQLServer monit
Код для вывода в Excel
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TestWS1
{
    public partial class ReportForm : Form
    {
        public ReportForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnGenerateReport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string reportType = cmbReportType.SelectedItem.ToString(); // Тип отчета
            DateTime startDate = dtpStartDate.Value; // Начало периода
            DateTime endDate = dtpEndDate.Value; // Конец периода

            DataTable reportData = GenerateReport(reportType, startDate, endDate);

            if (reportData != null)
            {
                dgvReport.DataSource = reportData; // Отображение данных в DataGridView
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Данные для отчета не найдены.", "Отчет", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
        }

        private DataTable GenerateReport(string reportType, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
        {
            string query = string.Empty;

            // Генерация SQL-запроса на основе типа отчета
            switch (reportType)
            {
                case "Успеваемость":
                    query = @"
                        SELECT s.first_name + ' ' + s.last_name AS StudentName,
                               sub.subject_name AS Subject,
                               g.grade AS Grade,
                               g.grade_date AS Date
                        FROM Grades g
                        JOIN Students s ON g.student_id = s.student_id
                        JOIN Subjects sub ON g.subject_id = sub.subject_id
                        WHERE g.grade_date BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate";
                    break;

                case "Активность преподавателей":
                    query = @"
                        SELECT t.first_name + ' ' + t.last_name AS TeacherName,
                               COUNT(g.grade_id) AS TotalGradesGiven
                        FROM Grades g
                        JOIN Teachers t ON g.teacher_id = t.teacher_id
                        WHERE g.grade_date BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate
                        GROUP BY t.first_name, t.last_name";
                    break;

                default:
                    MessageBox.Show("Выберите корректный тип отчета.");
                    return null;
            }

            // Подключение к базе данных
            using (SqlConnection connection = DatabaseHelper.GetConnection())
            {
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
                {
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startDate", startDate);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@endDate", endDate);

                    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
                    DataTable table = new DataTable();
                    adapter.Fill(table);

                    return table;
                }
            }
        }

        private void btnExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (dgvReport.DataSource == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Нет данных для экспорта.");
                return;
            }

            SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog
            {
                Filter = "Excel Files|*.xlsx",
                Title = "Сохранить отчет"
            };

            if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string filePath = saveFileDialog.FileName;
                ExportToExcel(filePath, (DataTable)dgvReport.DataSource);
                MessageBox.Show("Отчет успешно сохранен!", "Экспорт", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
        }

        private void ExportToExcel(string filePath, DataTable data)
        {
            using (var workbook = new ClosedXML.Excel.XLWorkbook())
            {
                var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add("Отчет");
                for (int i = 0; i < data.Columns.Count; i++)
                {
                    worksheet.Cell(1, i + 1).Value = data.Columns[i].ColumnName; // Заголовки
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < data.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < data.Columns.Count; j++)
                    {
                        worksheet.Cell(i + 2, j + 1).Value = data.Rows[i][j]?.ToString() ?? string.Empty; // Безопасное преобразование в строку

                    }
                }

                workbook.SaveAs(filePath);
            }
        }
    }
}


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestWS1
{
    public static class GradesDB
    {
        public static DataTable GetGrades(int studentId)
        {
            string query = @"
                            SELECT grade_id, subject_id, grade, grade_date
                            FROM Grades
                            WHERE student_id = @studentId";

            using (SqlConnection connection = DatabaseHelper.GetConnection())
            {
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
                {
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@studentId", studentId);

                    using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
                    {
                        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
                        adapter.Fill(dataTable);
                        return dataTable;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public static DataTable GetStudents()
        {
            string query = "SELECT student_id, first_name + ' ' + last_name AS full_name FROM Students";

            using (SqlConnection connection = DatabaseHelper.GetConnection()) // Метод Database.GetConnection() уже реализован
            {
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
                {
                    using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
                    {
                        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
                        adapter.Fill(dataTable);
                        return dataTable; // Возвращаем DataTable с данными студентов
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


FormGrade
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TestWS1
{
    public partial class GradesForm : Form
    {
        public GradesForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            LoadStudents();
        }
        private void LoadStudents()
        {
            DataTable students = GradesDB.GetStudents(); // Предполагается, что метод для получения студентов уже реализован
            comboStudents.DataSource = students;
            comboStudents.DisplayMember = "full_name";  // Отображаемое имя
            comboStudents.ValueMember = "student_id";  // Идентификатор
        }
        private void LoadGrades(int studentId)
        {
            DataTable grades = GradesDB.GetGrades(studentId);
            dataGridViewGrades.DataSource = grades;
        }

        private void comboStudents_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (comboStudents.SelectedValue is int studentId)
            {
                LoadGrades(studentId);
                CalculateAverageGrade(studentId);
            }
        }

        private void CalculateAverageGrade(int studentId)
        {
            DataTable grades = GradesDB.GetGrades(studentId);

            if (grades.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                decimal total = grades.AsEnumerable().Sum(row => row.Field<decimal>("grade"));
                decimal average = total / grades.Rows.Count;
                lblAverageGrade.Text = $"Средняя оценка: {average:F2}";
            }
            else
            {
                lblAverageGrade.Text = "Нет данных об оценках.";
            }
        }

    }
}


Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Вопрос то в чём у вас? )
